# Upload files via request python library to a php server

Tags: php, python, post, request, forms, http-post

I am trying to upload to an apache2 server. I have a python based application which uses a code like

```
import requests
files = {'userfile': open('sty.png', 'rb')}
r = requests.put('http://localhost/upload/upload_file.php',files=files)           
print r.text
```

the PHP responds with the final address of the uploaded file.
Doing this with the help of an HTML is working using $_FILES argument. 
This is showing an error

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: does not show any error. It works when I pass some string as a POST parameter
but for a file it goes directly to the exception handling part

Comment: And what exception does it raise? What message does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you should not use `PUT` in your request, but `POST`. You see, the working HTML form you have is likely using `POST` to send the form data. Just change your code to:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/upload/upload_file.php',files=files)
```

And try again.